# R grouping values in data table for pie chart

Tags: r, pie-chart

I have some statistic data about process quality presented in table form (result >> % of all cases)

```
# (df <- read.csv(...)
detection_quality_algo1_pupil <- table(df$pupeuclid1)
detection_quality_algo1_pupil_percent = round(
        detection_quality_algo1_pupil[names(detection_quality_algo1_pupil)] 
        / nrow(df) 
        * 100
   , digits = 1)
```

0 - 16.4%

1 - 50.6%

2 - 12.0%

3 - 2.4%

etc.

```
> detection_quality_algo1_pupil_percent

    0    1    2    3    4    5   10   11   12   13   16   17   20   21   22   23   24   25   27   29   30   31   32   33 
16.4 50.6 12.0  2.4  0.5  0.6  0.9  0.6  0.3  0.1  0.3  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.3  0.3  0.1  0.1  0.3  0.1  0.3  0.1  0.1 
  37   40   43   45   50   53   54   55   56   59  102  104  106  107  112  114  131  132  134  136  138  139  141  142 
 0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.4  0.1  0.3  0.1  0.1  0.3  0.1  0.1 
 145  149  150  151  152  153  154  155  156  157  158  160  161  164  166  167  168  169  170  171  173  175  187  191 
 0.3  0.6  0.1  0.3  0.1  0.5  0.3  0.1  0.1  0.4  0.1  0.1  0.4  0.1  0.1  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.1  0.3  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1 
 194  208 
 0.1  0.1 

> pie(detection_quality_algo1_pupil_percent)
```

[image]

my goal is grouping results with value > 3 into one big group named "> 3" and show results on pie chart.

I think it's about applying some filters on source table...
How can i do this?

Comment: http://darkhorseanalytics.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/devourThePie3.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
x <- rep(0:5,c(20,50,20,4,4,2))
pie(table(x))                                  # 3 small groups
pie(table(cut(x, c(-Inf,0:2,Inf),labels=0:3))) # 1 group representing the 3 small groups
```

And, as @sebpardo notes, pie charts are terrible. Use a barplot instead:

```
barplot(table(cut(x, c(-Inf,0:2,Inf),labels=0:3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a new 'collapsed' column to your dataframe using `mutate`, e.g.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate(df, new_group = ifelse(group > 3, ">3", group)
```

I agree with @sebpardo's suggestion in the comment above that there's a better way to visualize data than pie charts. Even the help page advises against them (see `?pie`):

> "Pie charts are a very bad way of displaying information. [...]"